# how to convert datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 18, 55, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 19800)) to 2019-01-08 11:49:00.000000 in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I had received format like this in python

> datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 18, 55, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 19800))

need to convert like this

> 2020-3-5 18:55:00.000000

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

import arrow
arrow.get(str(date_str)).shift(hours=-5, minutes=-30).datetime